# Is it okay to put parts of my contract online without naming client or employer?

Tags: discussion

I just broke a contract in about one month to leave for a better job. The reasons are justifiable. The employer is asking me some questions which I think are meant to trick me into not getting my wages.

I want to put about 10% of my contract on this forum because I have some questions about the contract. I will make that as a separate question. I will NOT include any confidential information such as employer name, client name, trade secrets, salary, locations etc. I will only mention conditions like "If you terminate the contract before 1 year, then will not pay you last month's salary".

Can I do this ? I want to know before I put this info out here. I am sure it will make a good question for SO. I could rephrase it if you want. I understand that rephrasing might alter the meaning, but I will take great care to see it does not happen.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions about a contract should be referred to an attorney who specializes in employment law. Valid legal advice cannot be obtained here, for a large number of reasons.

Comment: @alroc - not asking legal advice. just trying to know if my former employer is trying to trick me possibly or for sure.

Comment: An attorney would still be the most appropriate person to answer such a question. What seems "tricky" to me might be perfectly acceptable in your jurisdiction.

Comment: Hi Japanese Crow, this is unfortunately unanswerable without a considerable amount of information and knowledge of employment law and confidentiality agreements. In addition this is going to be very specific to your contract and jurisdiction. As a result, since you are essentially asking for interpretation of your specific law/contract it's not really within the scope defined in the [Help Center](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Your employer can't trick you if you refuse to answer their questions.  If they want to build a case against you, let them do that without your help.

Answer (score 9):

To repeat what all the comments have said: take this to an attorney. Do NOT crowdsource legal advice, or specific contract questions, especially if there's an element of "is the other party trying to trick me" in your questions.

To answer the questions you're proposing to ask, anyone answering you would need to:

- see the full exact text of your contract
- be highly conversant with the labor laws under which the contract was governed

Anything else...you may get incorrect or incomplete answers to your questions, which could cause you to take actions that would make your situation worse.

Answer (score 7):

1. From the perspective of Stack Exchange, it is your responsibility to make sure you have the rights to share your contract
2. Even if it is legal to share, that does not guarantee there will be no consequences from doing it
3. Even if you shared it, legal questions are generally off-topic here

Basically, even if it is okay, you probably are better off not sharing because we probably won't be able to answer your question here.

#### Are you okay sharing your contract?

Here is what our [Content Policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy) says:

> **Copyright.** Using copyrighted material does not constitute infringement in all cases. In general, however, users should be careful when using copyrighted content without the permission of those who created it. It is our policy to respond to notices of alleged infringement that comply with the Digital Millennium Copyright Act ("DMCA").

So from our perspective (as SE), it is your responsibility to ensure that you aren't infringing on anyone's rights when you share content here. Whether or not you have that right is a separate question.

#### Sharing is not without consequence (even if legal)

Just because it is theoretically legal to share your contract doesn't mean that your employer cannot raise a stink, cannot bring you to court anyway, or otherwise make your life miserable. Just because you *can* share something doesn't mean you *should* share something.

#### We do not do legal advice here

It seems like your ultimate purpose is to ask for legal advice from our community. [Legal questions are off-topic here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/are-questions-of-law-is-x-legal-questions-off-topic) and are usually closed very promptly:

> Laws vary from state to state, locality to locality, and country to country. Furthermore, the laws change frequently, and sometimes interpretation of the law may be different than the actual case law.
>
> Since we intend this site to be a resource of helpful information, these questions must be explicitly disallowed and closed. Information is only helpful if it's correct, and since it's impossible to verify the accuracy of that information without consulting an attorney, we must close them.