# Is this question ontopic, and if not, where might it be ontopic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

> ### NDAs, non-competes, etc -- Do they expire, and if so, are there any limits to the use of knowledge?
>
> If the agreements date/term wise are legally expired, and there's no
>   additional IP agreements beyond them (copyright, patent, etc) - **what
>   legal/moral obligation do I have not to compete against the parties in
>   those agreements using the knowledge gain during the course of those
>   agreements?**
>
> Taking a step back, some might say that the party paid/owns the
>   related information, but my understanding is the spirit of the law for
>   IP long-term is that all IP enters the public domain, it's just a
>   matter of when/how/why/etc.
>
> **Also, is there a legally enforceable way to test the expiration of the agreements without potentially discovering the terms of said
>   agreement were violated by doing the test? If not, how do I define the
>   scope of limitation related to the use of knowledge covered by the
>   agreements?**
>
> ---
>
> **Legal Disclaimers:** Yes, I know: Seek the advice of an attorney; Your response is not legal advice; You are not an attorney, or your
>   response does not form attorney-client relationship; etc. I know,
>   thanks!

Comment: The question itself is based on way too many false assumptions.  I hesitate to believe that this would be a good question even on a site that accepts legal questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is purely a legal question and can only be answered by a lawyer.

There isn't currently a Stack Exchange site for legal questions, and unfortunately the two Area51 proposals, [Software Law](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3527/software-law)<sup>1</sup> and [Intellectual Property Law](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/why-intellectual-property-law-was-closed), that your question might have been on topic were closed.

Related Meta discussions:

- [Are questions of law ("is X legal?") questions off topic?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/are-questions-of-law-is-x-legal-questions-off-topic)
- [Are employment law questions off-topic?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29/are-employment-law-questions-off-topic)

<sub><sup>1</sup> I'm only mentioning Software Law because the question was asked and closed on Programmers.</sub>