# Why was this borderline legal question not only closed but deleted as well?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-questions

This question was closed and then deleted:

[What are the ramifications of a wrong id on a contract?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13511/what-are-the-ramifications-of-a-wrong-id-on-a-contract/13512#13512)

We have had several discussions on whether legal questions are on or off topic ([here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/are-questions-of-law-is-x-legal-questions-off-topic?rq=1) [here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/581/defining-the-on-topic-off-topic-line-on-questions-that-could-be-answered-by-a?rq=1) and [here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/what-is-asking-for-legal-advice) to name a few).

While asking, "What happens if my name is backwards for a contract signed under singapore law?" is definitely off-topic, knowing where to look in a contract for this information is rather general (clauses are very similar in most countries) seems to be relevant. While I can understand closing the question to try to refine it, is this question really so far beyond the line?

Is this really a clear line we should draw in the sand as a question that has absolutely no redeeming value to the site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, we try to exercise discretion when using the delete feature, leaving closed posts sit around so the community can review them, improve them, or vote to delete them.

In some cases, the question askers specifically request that their questions be removed, which happened in this case. When this happens on an open post, with many upvotes and an accepted answer, we try to do everything in our power to preserve the content and put in a request to disassociate the question from the user account, leaving "Anonymous" as the user name instead.

But for downvoted, closed questions with few upvotes, we lean towards just removing the post, since it's a time consuming process to disassociate an account. In this case, I'm not sure it's worth undeleting this post considering its low value and the fact that it's been closed for more than two weeks with no reopen votes or improvements.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't realize that it had been requested to have been deleted by the author. Is there any chance a comment could possibly be added to that extent? Does the delete option allow for comments on why?

Comment: I'm not sure we want to get on the habit of publicizing flags.  I made an exception here just because you asked, and it was the only way I could answer your question.  If you see something you think was done incorrectly, it's perfectly okay to bring it up here on a case by case basis.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the info. I just realized it had a real name attached, which is a good reason to have it removed at any rate.