# (Done) Reopen request: Appeals process of workplace question

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

This question was recently closed on the grounds that it asked for legal advice and was about a specific company: [Appeals process when employer fails to enroll an employee's dependent in health insurance](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/152903/appeals-process-when-employer-fails-to-enroll-an-employees-dependent-in-health)

If you look closely at the questions asked in the original post, this is explicitly not true. (I was, in fact, aware that asking for legal advice is neither allowed nor useful when I asked the question.) The question asks about resources and options outside of a lawsuit. The company is never named, and the question explicitly asks what can be done outside of the company. I do not think this closure is appropriate, or, if it is, it is not appropriate for the reasons given. If there is something in the question that is being interpreted as overly legalistic or accidentally requesting legal advice, I am happy to reword it, but the kinds of answers the question is asking for (and that I am looking for) can be found in, e.g., the first comment (Talk to your department of labor). I don't see how requesting this kind of information falls outside of the scope of workplace SO.

Edit: Apparently the comment I was thinking of has been deleted, or I'm misremembering where it showed up; regardless, the question is asking for resources like the department of labor, and that suggestion through SO was legitimately very useful for me, and likely would be for others.

Comment: This is getting down-voted, so clearly I'm missing something. Could I at least get an explanation of why the question violates the prohibition on legal advice & specific companies and how to ask for these kinds of resources without my question being closed?

Comment: Reference for legal guidelines: https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2423/what-criteria-do-we-need-for-questions-regarding-the-law-regulations-to-be-allow?rq=1

Comment: Question looks valid to me.. have cast a vote to re-open.

Comment: We encourage making seamless edits, i.e. ones that don't make it clear something is an edit, such as your "appeal" posted within the body. Instead focus on improving the question by dropping elements that might be read as asking for legal advice (whether correctly or not), shortening it if needed and clearly identifying the core (on-topic) question.

Comment: @TerrifiedEmployee I'm undecided to cast a vote to reopen. Leaving the legal aspect of the post aside, I feel that the questions you ask are a bit broad. Please consider focusing your questions ("what are my options" is quite broad, as well as "what other resources")... perhaps something more actionable? If you edit, consider pinging me so I can reconsider my vote

Comment: In my defense, I put the appeal in the question because another question about how to appeal posts in meta SO suggested doing exactly that. (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57104/how-to-appeal-a-closed-question)

Comment: @TerrifiedEmployee no need to "defend" yourself, It's ok :) things are a bit different here that on SO. Lilienthal is just kindy sharing feedback with you. What we usually do here is, write a Meta TWP post and then in a comment under your closed question say "This question is being discussed in meta [link]"

Comment: @DarkCygnus thanks; feeling a bit attacked on the site at the moment :-)

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. We surely don't intend to attack you (quite the contrary, if we reply is because are using our unpaid time to help you). I included a comment under your post as I mentioned. Just, be aware that no one is born knowing, and it may take a time for you to learn the differences of this Stack compared to others.

Comment: 4th reopen cast

Comment: @DarkCygnus are you referring to my question since I switched to the bullet points at the end (e.g., with the example of the department of labor)? or before that edit? I can tighten up the last bullet I suppose.

Comment: I was referring to *"Short of a lawsuit or talking to the press, what are my options? What other resources are there to help out and what should I be aware of?"* ... those questions are a bit broad to my taste, and is what I suggest you consider perhaps focusing.

Comment: @DarkCygnus Thanks; I have reworded the questions at the end of the post.

Comment: This has me wondering, though, whether there is space on SE for questions that essentially boil down to: something has happened in my workspace; the legal/regulatory landscape of this particular issue is very complicated, and I have failed to get my footing w.r.t. that landscape; what advice is there for helping me get started?"

Comment: @DarkCygnus just fyi, re:feeling attacked; from my perspective, my question got closed for reasons I didn't understand; I tried to research the appeals process and followed the instructions I found (admittedly I thought SO and SE shared a meta); my appeal on meta immediately got down-voted without explanation, then the first answer to my appeal stated agreement with the closure but no explanation; then I was told that I did the appeal wrong. I thought I had violated some norm that wasn't clear to me and that nobody wanted to talk about. I get why things happened how they did now.

Comment: @TerrifiedEmployee Fifth vote casted. Post open again :) also... don't take it too personal. In Meta votes don't mean "good/bad quality" they mean "I agree/don't"... you also posted this on MSE, which was not the correct thing to do... It's ok, you are learning your ways, surely next time you will do it smoothly... also, try not to "feel attacked"; in forums and online sites it's hard to read the tone and intention from comments, an a comment intended to help can be perceived as an "attack"... :)

Answer (score 2):

After some edits and improvements to the question from part of OP, I've casted the fifth and final vote, and now the post is open again for users to post their answers and suggestions.